# How to create boot cd from an already burned one?

Tags: installation, compact-disc, bootable-media

I have copied a knopix cd from my friend. But unfortunately the cd was not a bootable one.I have already copied all of the contents and when I run from windows it works fine.

How can I enable the bootable option to the cd now ?

I am using the nero express for burning.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 1):

You just can't.
Even if the cd session is not closed, you can add datas, but not those necessary to transform it at a boot cd.

The price of a cd is so low that you really better have to burn another one rather than searching for an hypothetical workaround.